# How can I make a stylesheet where inline cells are styled like input cells?

Tags: cells, stylesheet, syntax-highlighting

How can I make a stylesheet where inline cells are styled like input cells? By "similar", I mean the same font and syntax highlighting.

I have even tried copying all settings from `Input` cell of `Core.nb` to a private style definition for `InlineCell`, but had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looked like I had misunderstood "syntax highlighting" in this context.
What I need turned out to be `ShowCodeAssist->True`. Combining this and settings on font and others that looked relevant:

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"],
ShowAutoStyles->True, 
ShowCodeAssist->True,
LanguageCategory->"Mathematica",
FormatType->"InputForm",
FontFamily->"Courier New", 
FontWeight->"Bold"]
```

I finally achieved what was almost what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the [`DefaultInlineFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultInlineFormatType) for "Text" cells to `DefaultInputInlineFormatType` (i.e., "StandardForm"), and change the style "InlineCell" to inherit options from "Input":

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Text"], DefaultInlineFormatType -> System`DefaultInputInlineFormatType],
        Cell[StyleData["InlineCell", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]]]
        }
    ]
]
```

Here is screen capture from a notebook, showing a text cell with an inline cell, followed by a normal "Input" cell, so that you can compare them:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't get syntax highlighting in an inline cell. Syntax highlighting is not a style, but a function of the front end's code editor, which is only active in Input cells. You *can* put text in a text cell into Input style. Select the text, then type <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (Windows).

Comment: thanks. Can I set upright font shape in stylesheet so that single character will not get automatically slanted?

Comment: I just noticed that by typing Shift + Ctrl + I, inline cell can be converted to `InputForm`. Is there a way to automate this process?