# Is there a way to convert InlineCell to InputForm once and for all?

Tags: stylesheet

After asking [a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46329/how-can-i-make-a-stylesheet-where-inline-cells-have-are-styled-like-input-cells) about making InlineCell similar to Input, I realized that by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> I really can manually convert every InlineCell to InputForm.

So my new question is: Is there a way to make this conversion once and for all? Or is there a way to automate this conversion for all InlineCells? (maybe programmatically?)