# Syntax highlighting in text cells

Tags: front-end, cells, style, syntax-highlighting

I want to write some documentation for a notebook using text cells. Now, I can select parts of the text within such a text cell and set its style to "Input". This does change its font, but there is no syntax highlighting (neither the right color nor are patterns slanted). Is it possible to add styles and syntax coloring to inline cells so that they look like input cells?

Comment: Strongly related: ["How can I make a stylesheet where inline cells are styled like input cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199438/280)

Answer (score 9):

According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103315/280), there is a way to make an inline cell with automatic syntax highlighting. For example we can create a `"Text"` cell containing an inline `"Input"` cell with automatic syntax highlighting:

```
CellPrint@TextCell[
  Row[{"This is an inline cell with automatic syntax highlighting: ", 
    ExpressionCell[Defer@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "string"], "Notebook", "Input", 
     CellFrame -> True]}], "Text"]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `ShowAutoStyles -> True` is not a sufficient condition for syntax highlighting. The cell also must be an input cell and be displayed in standard form.

Comment: @m_goldberg I updated the answer and removed previous hasty conclusions.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a bit. Unfortunately, the input subcell is incompatible with `Magnification`, i.e. it is very small on my 4K-monitor. Removing the `"Notebook"` option fixes this but removes the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Berg I can't test right now but try to add the option Magnification -> Inherited at the end.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the [`DefaultInlineFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultInlineFormatType) option of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) cells to "StandardForm", and then set the [`LanguageCategory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LanguageCategory) and [`ShowAutoStyles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowAutoStyles) options of "InlineCell" to achieve what you want. For example:

```
styles = {
    Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"],
        ShowAutoStyles->True,
        LanguageCategory->"Input",
        FontWeight->"DemiBold",
        FontFamily->"Source Sans Pro"
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Text"],
        DefaultInlineFormatType->"StandardForm"
    ]
};

SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Replace[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions],
        {
        Notebook[oldcells_, r__] :> Notebook[Join[oldcells, styles], r],
        other_ :> Notebook[Prepend[styles, Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->other]]], StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
        }
    ]
]
```

Input cells are in [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm), and use the DemiBold version of the "Source Sans Pro" font. Syntax coloring occurs when both [`ShowAutoStyles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowAutoStyles) and [`ShowSyntaxStyles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowSyntaxStyles) are true, and the [`LanguageCategory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LanguageCategory) is "Input". I don't need to specify the [`ShowSyntaxStyles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowSyntaxStyles) option because it is true by default for [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm). Here is an example text cell with this stylesheet:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Syntax highlighting is a property peculiar to  input cells and doesn't pertain to a `StyleBox`, which is what your get when you apply the style `Input` to a selection made in a text cell.