# How to use an ExpressionCell to display e.g. an Input cell inside a generated output?

Tags: front-end, cells, style, inheritance

It's not that I can't live with that but I don't understand why e.g:

```
ExpressionCell[ Defer @ Style["string", Red], "Input"]
```

[image]

is not showing quote marks? This means that a `ShowStringCharacters` option is not inherited from an `"Input"` style, as one (at least me) would expect, but (probably) from an `"Output"`.

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #, ShowStringCharacters}] & /@ {"Input", "Output"}
```

> ```
> {True, False}
> ```

---

Can this be explained with documentation?

Maybe I'm missing the point of an `ExpressionCell`?

---

With `CellPrint` everything will be ok, but it's not what I'm after because I'd like to use an `ExpressionCell` as a part of the output somewhere to quickly format an InputStyle, eg:

```
Column[{
  "here is an example of the input cell:",
  ExpressionCell[Defer@Style["string", Red], "Input"]
} ]
```

Comment: When you evaluate ExpressionCell in an input cell, the result will be an output cell, and therefore you do not see the quotation marks. I do not have a good understanding of EvaluationCells and TextCells, but my feeling is that they are supposed not to be used as stand alone commands, but as arguments of functions such as CellPrint. As you observed, then it works as expected.

Comment: ExpressionCells are baffling to me as well! They use interpretation boxes, so this would work: `CopyToClipboard@ExpressionCell[Defer@
    Style["string", Red], "Input"];Paste[]`

Comment: @FredSimons Ok, I've read a little bit and it seems to be logical at the end :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after taking a look at `Core.nb` stylesheet it is clear what happens.

What's there is a `Notebook` setting of `ShowStringCharacters->True` and `ShowStringCharacters->False` are included only in styles that need it to be `False`, like an `Output`. `Input` just inherits from the `Notebook`.

---

By evaluating `ExpressionCell[ Defer @ Style["string", Red], "Input"]` we get something which inherits style in following way:

> Output styles (from the cell it was put in) --> Input styles (from the ExpressionCell)

`Input` styles are superior since ExpressionCell is the inner one. But `ShowStringCharacters` is not set explicitly in `Core.nb` for `Input` style.

---

So at the end we get:

- `ShowStringCharacters->True` from `Notebook` settings, which
- is overwritten by `ShowStringCharacters->False` from `Output` settings, and
- an `Input` `ExpressionCell` is passing it because there is no spec in stylesheet about `ShowStringCharacters` for `Input`.

---

How to get nice `Input` like `ExpressionCell` then? We can put `Notebook` styles in between outer `Output` and `ExpresisonCell` `Input` styles:

```
Panel @ ExpressionCell[
    Defer @ Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "string"], 
    "Notebook", "Input"
]
```

[image]

Now, it looks like real `Input` cell. With syntax coloring etc.