# Dynamic InputField with syntax highlighting?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, inputfield, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a notebook where a user can enter a Mathematica expression, and its syntax is analyzed (number of tokens, compressed size, etc.).

Trying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92223/61597),

```
CellPrint@TextCell[
  Row[{"This is an inline cell with automatic syntax highlighting: ", 
    ExpressionCell[Dynamic@input, "Notebook", "Input", 
     CellFrame -> True]}], "Text"]
Dynamic@input
```

the Dynamic doesn't update `input`. If I make an `InputField` inside the `ExpressionCell` the syntax highlighting doesn't apply, even if I change the `BaseStyle`. How can I get both dynamic behavior and syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
x = ToBoxes@Defer@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];

InputField[Dynamic[x], Boxes, 
 BaseStyle -> {"Notebook", "Input", ShowCodeAssist -> True, ShowSyntaxStyles -> True}
]

Dynamic@x
Dynamic@MakeExpression[StripBoxes[x], StandardForm]
```

[image]

Comment: If I add whitespace inside that field, `MakeExpression` fails and generates `ErrorBox`es; this is frustrating because the user cannot paste in input or add whitespace. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @lirtosiast I added `StripBoxes` to be less strict about the content.