# Is it possible to substitute one style with another via Stylesheet?

Tags: notebooks, cells, style, stylesheet, inheritance

When thinking on the question

- [How to programmatically change CellStyle of all Cells from "Input" to "Code"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/258539/280)

it crossed my mind that it may be possible to "intercept" one style (`"Input"`) on the level of the Notebook's private stylesheet and replace it with definitions of another style (`"Code"`) from  the "Core.nb" stylesheet. Something like the following (it demonstrates the idea, but doesn't work):

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"], StyleData["Code", StyleDefinitions -> "Core.nb"]]]
```

The above line of code defines an "intercept" for the style `"Input"` on the level of the Notebook's private stylesheet. The second argument `StyleData["Code", StyleDefinitions -> "Core.nb"]` should "import" the complete definition for style `"Code"` from the "Core.nb" stylesheet, but it doesn't work as written. How should it be changed in order to achieve the desired goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199438/280), the syntax should be:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]]]
```

Setting the option programmatically:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]]]
        }
    ]
]
```

Checking:

[image: screenshot]

As one can see, the input cell is formatted as a `"Code"` cell, while in its definition it still has the style `"Input"`. Done!